# Clear spefic Internet cache vb6.0

Tags: caching, vb6, browser-cache

When I download a textfile to read the content, the next time I do not get the the changed content of the file. Somehow the cache file is read and not the updated file on the Internet site.
Is there a way to delete a specific file from cache straight after downloading and reading it?

```
'API used:

Public Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

'Internet Read Text File Content
If FileExists(FileToCreate) = True Then
  Kill (FileToCreate) ' kill it to make sure it is created by this routine
End If

If INetThere = True Then ' checks if there is an Internet connection

On Error Resume Next ' Issue with Digital Certification, to be resolved later.
    BaK = URLDownloadToFile(0, FileToGet, FileToCreate, 0, 0)
On Error GoTo 0
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox (Err.Number)
End If

If FileExists(FileToCreate) Then ' get content: CACHE problem, reads old file from memory instead of Internet file content
    VrijeFile = FreeFile
    Open FileToCreate For Input As #VrijeFile
    Line Input #VrijeFile, VersionBAK ' this line gets the data from the old, previously read file in chache
    Close #VrijeFile
    Kill (FileToCreate)
End If

If VersionBAK <> "" Then
  LeesRegeL = VersionBAK
  UpdateMajor = VBA.Val(VBA.Trim$(Chop_On(vbDot)))
  UpdateMinor = VBA.Val(VBA.Trim$(Chop_On(vbDot)))
  UpdateRevision = VBA.Val(VBA.Trim$(LeesRegeL))
End If

New_LCWin_Version = (UpdateMajor > LCWinMajoR) Or (UpdateMinor > LCWinMinoR) Or (UpdateRevision > LCWinReviSioN)

CheckForUpdate = New_LCWin_Version ' end result for the function returned
```

Comment: There isn't enough detail. Please edit the question to add some minimal code that would help to understand what your program is doing.

Comment: added the code to clarify

Comment: issue resolved (see below), thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved:

The file was not made public by the Internet provider although I could view the new content of the file, it was not available for the public, the old one was.

Therefore it is not the cache that is not updated, it is the website itself.

thanks for viewing and contributing.

Case closed and hopefully helpful for others.